# jQuery delay addClass

Tags: jquery, methods, delay

How can I delay addClass in jQuery? I tried but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box1").delay(600).addClass("animated bounce");
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method helps to provide a delay between animation queue. In your case, you need to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $(".box1").addClass("animated bounce"); 
  },600)
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".box1").addClass("animated bounce");
  }, 600)
});
```

```css
.box1,
.box2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #62a6c9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Comment: I tried but id doesn't work:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Graphikku/obnhhdyz/

Comment: @R.Catalin : simple typo... updated :)

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem! I typed something wrong..